# Can you make a Moq mock of an interface pass a cast and null check of a type that implements that interface?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

Specifically in my case if Foo was a property IBar, and I have mocked Foo.

```
if (!(Foo is Bar bar))
{
    Logger.Error("ERROR, NOT CORRECT TYPE");
    return false;
}
```

I'd like to make my `Mock<IBar>` not `Mock<Bar>` if possible.

---

Complete unsnippeted example:

Bar class, what Foo property is "cast" to:

```
public class Bar : IBar
{
    // Stuff I don' care about because I am using a mock
}
```

Test Class:

```
[TestClass]
public class InuEmulatorCustomBehaviourBaseTests
{
    Mock<IBar> _IBarMock;

    [TestInitialize]
    public void TestInitialise()
    {
        _IBarMock= new Mock<IBar>();

        // Code used to set up a spy to check log messages produced during each test
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void UnitUnderTest_Initialise_LogsNoErrors_when_Foo_is_of_type_Bar_Test()
    {
         //Arrange
         var unitUnderTest = new UnitUnderTest { Foo = _IBarMock.Object };

         //Act
         unitUnderTest.Initialise();

         //Assert
         Assert.AreEqual(0, _spiedLogMessage.Count, "An error was logged when none should have been.");
    }

    [TestCleanup]
    public void TestCleanup()
    {
        // Code used to reset the spy to check log messages produced during each test
    }
}
```

And the UnitUnderTestClass:

```
public class UnitUnderTest
{
    IBar _foo;
    public IBar Foo
    {
        private get
        {
            return _foo ?? _foo = new Bar(); 
        }
        set { _foo = value; } //set as new Mock<IBar> during unit test
    }

    public bool Initialise()
    {
        if (!(Foo is Bar bar))
        {
            Logger.Error("ERROR, NOT CORRECT TYPE");
            return false; //don't want my test to follow this path
        }
        return true; //want my test to follow this path
    }
}
```

I understand WHY the above test fails, I'd like to know if I can and how to pass it without using a `Mock<Bar>`.

Comment: Currently unclear what it is you are asking. Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I can´t see neither an interface nor any mock. It´s really hard to get what you´re asking, unless you don´t provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Could you be more specific yourself? I have/can mock Foo, a C# property, I wish to pass this check without entering the if statement but with using Mock<IBar> not Mock<Bar>

Comment: @HimBromBeere I'm unsure what you mean, I state Foo is a property of interface IBar, Bar is obviously of interface IBar through naming conventions.

Comment: @Shefeto naming convention or not, don't make such assumptions. Be clear when asking questions so those volunteering to help you can do without having to guess what it is you are trying to explain. consider reviewing [ask] to improve your question.

Comment: @Nkosi I've made it explicit now

Comment: I suppose you want your `Foo`-property to be of a different type than `Bar`. By mocking the property of an interface-type a new (anonymously) type is created that implements the `IBar`-interface (something like `IBarProxy`). Thus `Foo is Bar` should never return `true`.

Comment: However in your case it seems to be true thus you probably made something whrong on your mock. However we can´t know as you didn´t provide any information on your mock.

Comment: @HimBromBeere added it so you can check.

Comment: @Shefeto show a [mcve] that can be used to reproduce the problem. These snippets are incomplete and only cause more confusion. For example you show one line of mock but we have no clue how the rest of the test is arranged or exercised.

Comment: You still didn´t show how `_IMockBar` relates to `Foo`. *How* do you assign that property?

Comment: @HimBromBeere I'm working on this MCV example Nkosi asked for atm, but to quickly answer your question it is just set, before the problem code (at the top) is called. A simple `UnitUnderTest.Foo = _IBarMock.Object;`

Comment: you can´t *assign* a mocked instance, you have to mock the instance that has the property *also*. Something like `myInstance.Setup(x => x.Foo).Returns(myMock)`.

Comment: @HimBromBeere, look at the full MVC I've edited in, I've mocked out Foo by setting the property, the setter is public, it's just how our team does Mocking but it is irrelevant and isn't my problem anyway.

Comment: @Nkosi Done the MCV, please take a look.

Comment: @HimBromBeere@Nkosi Also I noticed that the generic types got lost without my knowledge due to the markup, I've fixed all the ones I could find which should drastically improve comprehension.

Comment: @Shefeto ok based on shown code the only way for that test to pass is if you have a `Bar` derived class to satisfy the `if (!(Foo is Bar bar))` condition. So assuming `Bar` is not sealed, you either mock `Bar` or Stub it manually and pass that to the SUT.

Comment: "I understand WHY the above test fails" Me not, As I already said `Foo is Bar` whouldn´t return true, as `Foo` as a `IMockProxy` (or similar, don´t know the exact name in Moq).

Comment: if creating an instance of `Bar` has knock on effects or unwanted behavior for the test then you would need to review the current design choice which focuses too much on implementation concerns.

Comment: @Nkosi, so your answer to my question is no, I cannot use `Mock<IBar>`? I guess I'll just stick with `Mock<Bar>` like I was before, shame I spent an hour for no improvement :/

Comment: @Shefeto wow, that markup omission in the OP made the world of difference in the understanding of the question. That `I'd like to make my Mock not Mock if possible.` is what completely threw me off.

Comment: @Nkosi don't blame you, I don't want to make excuses but I don't think it's uncommon for people to subconsciously fill in the errors like that when reading what they wrote.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IMHO this is not possible. The root cause is that your unit under test claims it would work with something that implements the interface (through the property type), but down in its implementation it tests for a specific implementation.

For me this is a big code smell, cause the unit under test should not rely on a specific implementation if it tells to the outer world it would it just needs a specific interface.

Maybe the method shouldn't test for a specific type, but instead if some property of `Foo`is set to a specific value, cause this could be easily mocked.

Comment: It does check the name afterwards as it turns out, however this is for a state machine, there's only one state it should be when calling Initialise and it fails because of the state not being right (deliberately fails), not because it wants to perform a cast later to Bar and use Bar specific members.

I do agree it's a bit redundant to check the name and type but it's just how I'm expected to keep it I'm afraid.